# How to Set width of div to 100% when second div hide by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have below code. I want to set width of blue div to 100% when I hide the red div. Any idea?
My Javascript code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").toggle(function() {
                $(this).text('Show Content');
            }, function() {
                $(this).text('Hide Content');
            }).click(function(){
                $("#red").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
        </script>
```

my style

```
<style>
        #red {

            width: 50%;
            border: 5px solid red;
            float: left
        }
        .blue {
            float: left;
            border: 5px solid #00F;
        }
        </style>
```

and my html code

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="button_style">Hide content</a> <br/>
<div id="red">Content</div>
<div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a class which assigns 100% width.

JS :

```
$("#red").slideToggle("slow",function(){
    $('.blue').toggleClass('fullWidth')
});
```

CSS :

```
.fullWidth{
    width:100%;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N8z2h/)**

Reference : **[toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**

Comment: one more thing can you pls tell me how can i hide red div from right to left instead of bottom to top?

Comment: You need to use animate/toggle for that, `slideToggle()` won't work . Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N8z2h/1/

Answer (score 4):

The version of toggle you are using is [deprecated: 1.8, removed: 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

The statement you are looking for could be

```
$("#red").next(".blue").css("width","100%");
```

or have an extra class and use `.toggleClass("wide");` where .wide has the desired width

Here is my suggestion which removes the deprecated toggle function from the button

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/84p6T/)

```
$(function() {
   $("#button").click(function(){
       var $red = $("#red"),
           hiding=$red.is(":visible"), 
           text = hiding?'Show Content':'Hide Content';
       $(this).text(text);
       $red.slideToggle("slow");
       $red.next(".blue").toggleClass("wide");
  });
});
```

I think you might want to play with animation instead

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/CpWP7/)

```
$(function() {
   $("#button").click(function(){
       var $red = $("#red"),
           $blue=$("#red").next(".blue"),
           hiding=!$red.hasClass("wide"), 
           text = hiding?'Show Content':'Hide Content';
       $(this).text(text);
       $red.animate({width:(hiding?0:100)+'%'},2000);
       $blue.animate({width:(hiding?100:0)+'%'},2000);
       $red.toggleClass("wide");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `width` of the `div` depending on the text

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").toggle(function () {
        $(this).text('Show Content');
        $('.blue').css('width', '100%');
    }, function () {
        $(this).text('Hide Content');
        $('.blue').css('width', 'auto');
    }).click(function () {
        $("#red").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LnL7e/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").toggle(function() {
            $(this).text('Show Content');
            $("#red").next(".blue").css("width","100%");
        }, function() {
            $(this).text('Hide Content');
            $("#red").next(".blue").css("width","46%");
        }).click(function(){
            $("#red").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

CSS :

```
 #red {

        width: 50%;
        border: 5px solid red;
        float: left
    }
    .blue {
        float: right;
        border: 5px solid #00F;
        width: 46%;
    }
```

Html:

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="button_style">Hide content</a> <br/>
    <div id="red">Content</div>
    <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
```

I think this is what you want.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk2uk/)